# kvm/qemu linux guest vm wont boot

Tags: virtual-machine, libvirt

host linux (kvm/qemu/libvirt) guest linux (slackware)
the slack vm pauses just after `Loading Linux-virtio......` message. it's stuck in paused state. i think i shutdown the host without shutting the vm down first. maybe that did something. libvirtd status output...

```
Mar 09 12:04:25 aries dnsmasq[482]: using nameserver 192.168.1.1#53
Mar 09 12:04:25 aries dnsmasq[482]: using local addresses only for unqualified names
Mar 09 12:04:25 aries dnsmasq[482]: read /etc/hosts - 6 addresses
Mar 09 12:04:25 aries dnsmasq[482]: read /var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/default.addnhosts - 0 addresses
Mar 09 12:04:25 aries dnsmasq-dhcp[482]: read /var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/default.hostsfile
Mar 09 12:17:11 aries libvirtd[3713]: libvirt version: 1.2.1
Mar 09 12:17:11 aries libvirtd[3713]: metadata not found: Requested metadata element is not present
Mar 09 12:17:11 aries libvirtd[3713]: internal error: unable to execute QEMU command 'qom-get': guest hasn't updated any stats yet
Mar 09 12:19:34 aries libvirtd[3713]: End of file while reading data: Input/output error
Mar 10 14:46:53 aries libvirtd[3713]: metadata not found: Requested metadata element is not present
```

i've done some searching but i dont think i'm asking the right questions.

the vm's xml is here .. http://pastebin.com/L3FY9aR7

libvirtd log level 2 here .. < http://pastebin.com/2uQH5gEW >

Comment: `libvirt metadata not found` it seems to be a libvirt problem, could you post related configs.

Comment: the vm's xml file is here <http://pastebin.com/L3FY9aR7 > is there anything else i should post?

Comment: In the examples section is explained how to debug http://libvirt.org/logging.html

Comment: nice, i posted a link to a pastbin of the log output. im reading thru the log and wiki. thx!

Comment: i deleted a snapshot the other day. i forgot about that. will that screw up the original image? I'll read over the libvirt snapshot page